# Выполнение команд cmd с помощью Си

Tags: c, windows, cmd

К примеру я хочу исполнить команду "cd" и получить ответ как в cmd только используя код на Си

Comment: См. в сторону `system()`

Comment: Команда `cd` вызванная в дочернем процессе приведёт к смене текущего каталога дочернего процесса. Когда процесс завершится, никаких следов ваших усилий не останется. Бессмысленно менять каталог таким образом. Что вы хотите сделать?